# SSD stopped working in laptop but works in other laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd

Strange thing happening in my dell xps l701x - I have been using it for years now with a hdd and sdd in it. The other day, I powered down and went out. Came back to find it would not boot into windows. It did not find OS. Upon startup i checked in the bios and it was only seeing one drive (the hdd).

Tried swaping the drives over but it would not see the ssd.

I have another laptop so I put the ssd into this laptop (i am actually using it right now) and it booted fine.

I put the ssd from this second laptop into the main laptop and it works, it also sees the hdd.

I previously thought the hard drive controller or port on the motherboard was gone on the l701x but now seeing it working with other drives I am not so sure. But that does not explain why the SSD would work in this laptop??????

The SSD in question is a OCZ vertex 4 (256gb). Could it be close to being on the way out?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution. Whilst having the SSD in the other laptop I did a firmware update - using ocz drive tools. Put it back in the l701x and bingo!

Does not answer the question of WHY this would happen suddenly though.